# Laptop Charger Confusing 65Watts or 120 Watts

Tags: laptop, power-supply

So when I check at asus website about the specification of the charger it shows this
https://www.asus.com/Laptops/X550JF/specifications/

Output:
19 V DC, 3.42 A, 120 W

Input:
110 -240 V AC, 50/60 Hz universal

But 19 V DC, 3.42 A = 65 watts what is the correct charger of this laptop 65watts or 120 Watts

BTW I purchase this laptop without a charger on eBay

Thank you for your help

Comment: Probably a typo, 120w is more than likely the input current draw.

Comment: I would contact ASUS Support and ask them what the correct charger is. Yes, it appears to be a typo, but we cannot answer this on behalf of ASUS.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for Asus X550JF adapter replacements most of them say you need 120W (6.32A) (like [here](https://www.laptop-power.co.uk/laptop-chargers/Asus/asus/series-x550jf/model-x550jf-1b.html)).

So I would go for a 120W adapter, usually you won't have a problem buying an adapter that can provide more power then necessary. If you buy a non-original power supply make sure to check if your laptop can deal with "unregulated" voltage or if it needs "regulated" voltage (and buy the power supply accordingly - and make sure it's the same voltage and that it has the same polarity on the plug).

Or you could just contact Asus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you think asus have a typo error on there website ?

Comment: I would say so, but the question which of the values is the typo.

Comment: Only ASUS can answer that question (as we noted earlier)

Comment: Amps times volts equals watts; "too many watts" with the proper voltage is OK. 19volts is very common and generic adapters for this device all seem to agree on the voltage, including both ASUS citations.

Comment: yes it 120 watts " hey Name thanks for holding your device comes with a 120W19V 3PIN charger I am just looking to find it on our store for you.thank you so much for your help so this charger is DC output: 19V 6.32A not 3.42A"

Comment: @GalitAko sure thing, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should contact ASUS to get correct information.

19 Volts (yes is common today) x 3.4 amps = 65 watts, not 120 watts as the ASUS spec says. It is wrong and ASUS should correct.

Comment: I just chat with asus and they confirm it ship with 120watts ""hey Name thanks for holding your device comes with a 120W19V 3PIN charger I am just looking to find it on our store for you.thank you so much for your help so this charger is DC output: 19V 6.32A not 3.42A"

Comment: So that corrects the article that says 65 watts.

Comment: Yes , the customer support confirm that it use 120watts charger " this is the part number # 0A001-00060400 " and i suggest to change the 3.42A to 6.32A , i'm just curios as this laptop is not really a gaming laptop and use 120watts

Comment: You should probably use hte charger ASUS suggests. That will ensure it charges fully at a reasonable speed.